# Instagram Graph API Insights - Reach between two dates

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

In Instagram, the `reach` metric is a de-duplicated data source. In other words, the sum of 7 days worth of data does not necessarily equal the value for that week. This is similar to the Facebook Marketing `reach` metric.

I'd like to support this scenario: given two dates, give me the `reach` between those two dates.

In the FB Marketing API this is easily achieved using the `since` and `until` parameters to define the date boundaries, and then using a `time_increment` of `all_days` to retrieve the `reach` summed up across all those days.

For example, using the [FB Marketing API Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/insights/) here is a FB Marketing url that requests a week's worth of data summed up:

`{adaccount_id}/insights?metric=reach&since=2018-02-05&until=2018-02-11&time_increment=all_days`

In the Instagram Graph API I can define a `since` and `until` parameter to define the date boundaries, but there is no parameter like `time_increment`.

Using the [Instagram Graph API Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/insights), here is a url that requests a week's worth of data split up by day:

`{instagram_business_account_id}/insights?metric=reach&period=day&since=1517788800&until=1518307200`

Is there any way to change that around to get the summed up reach between two dates? I had hoped for a `period` option of `all_days` similar to the FB Marketing API's `time_increment` parameter but that doesn't exist.

Comment: What does your call currently return? Reach broken down by day? I would have thought your call was correct and that it returns a rolled up value

Comment: @PatrickLambe the call currently returns reach broken down by day unfortunately

Comment: Ah ok I see, and period=total_over_range doesn't work?

Comment: @PatrickLambe That gives me the error: `The following periods (total_over_range) are incompatible with the metric (reach)`